# Error with Perceptron

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

Since 1 week, i try to do a Perceptron neural network with one layer(in Java). I use an function Heavyside to calculate the exit of neurons, and the algorithme of Widrow-Hoff for the machine learning. 
My problem is, after the learning, i give some example to my computer and sometimes he answers correctly, sometimes he answers badly. So my question is : "It's possible for a computer, after the learning, he give me a bad answers?"

For exemple, I give this:
                      1 and 1 = ?

The first time, he give me : 1, 
The second time : 0, 
The third time : 1

Comment: Yes, it's possible for humans to give you the wrong answer after "learning" also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are learning using a gradient descent algorithm then the network can converge to a sub-optimal solution. 
In order to combat this you can try modifying your learning rate or using a decaying learning rate.